# Using entries from custom block library in twig template?

Tags: theming, blocks

I have two custom library blocks for the footer of a website I am developing. The idea is that admins may change the footer quite freely with a wysiwyg editor without any theme changes.

The problem is that I don't find any way to use only the contents of the custom library blocks (without the Drupal generated layout destructing code) in the footer twig.

Am I trying to do something impossible or just missing something obvious?

wbr

hank

Comment: Is the question “how do I remove the wrapping markup from rendered blocks”? Or something more subtle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and

```
{{ drupal_entity('block_content', 123) }}
```

This renders only the block content, without a block template.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for :) Thank you very much.